# Merge [office-2013] into [microsoft-office-2013]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Currently, [office-2013](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2013) and [microsoft-office-2013](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2013) are separate tags.  Can someone merge the former into the latter?

[microsoft-office-2013](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2013) should be the canonical tag, given that:

- [microsoft-office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2010) has a synonym [office-2010](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2010),
- [microsoft-office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2007) has a synonym [office-2007](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2007), and
- [microsoft-office-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-2003) has a synonym [office-2003](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2003).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done and done! Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: Oliver, on similar lines can you create a "microsoft-office-2011" tag and make the existing "office-2011" tag a synonym of it?

Comment: @Karan: Sounds good. Done.